# What happens when you request for more MPI tasks than the available physical cores/processors?

Tags: python, parallel-processing, mpi

I tried to run a parallel python script which uses mpi4py module.

mpirun -np 40 python compute.py

I requested for 40 MPI tasks and still the code ran successfully. I am not sure if my system has so many physical cores/processors. I am wondering how MPI or the linux kernel handles a situation like this.

Thank you for your comments.

Comment: Point your favourite search engine at *MPI oversubscription*.  You'll even find a few Qs and As here on the topic.

Comment: Thank you. I'll have a look at it.